# How to “pinch move”?

Tags: bluestacks

I'm using the free app Magic Poser on Bluestacks, which is a poser tool. One of the functions you'll need is to zoom in and out or to move the camera.

Zooming in and out is done on a real smartphone by pinching. I already figured out how it works with Bluestacks: hold ctrl and simply scroll up or down.

What I can't figure out it is how to move the camera. On a real smartphone, you do this by touching the screen with two fingers, just like with the zoom function, but you move your fingers across the screen to where you want the camera to be. How can I do this with Bluestacks?

Comment: Can the answers to this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/177564) be of help? One involves DroidMote, the other activating swipe.

Comment: @simlev I couldn't get the swipe one to work and I don't really want DroidMote. What's the point of using a smartphone app on your computer when you have to use the smartphone either way? At that point, I might as well just use the app like normal using my smartphone.